# convert a phrase to numbers in C

Tags: c, arrays, converters

How can i convert a phrase which the user gives into numbers but not with ASCII table ? For example, I have the phrase HELLO WORLD and i have an array in wich <> is 0, A is 1, B is 2, etc. please Help ! My problem is that i cannot find a way to compare two arrays.
I have started my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char  text[]={'         ','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','.',',',':','?'};
char number[125];

main(){
    int i,j;
    printf("Enter a message to encode:");
    gets(number);
}
```

but I have problems continouing it

Comment: You may need to read up on how characters are stored by computer systems.  A good place to start would be [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_characters).  Also follow some of the links so you can get an appreciation of other ways in which characters are represented and why they may change. This sounds like a homework assignment IMHO, so you should really do your homework to discover why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every char is basically a smaller int. The value is a value from [ascii](http://asciitable.com/) chart that encodes every letter. As you see, the letters are in 2 continuous blocks (one for upper case and one for lower case). So, for your result to be correct, you need to convert all letters to same case. You may use [tolower](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/tolower/?kw=tolower) or [toupper](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/toupper/) functions.
Then, you just need to subtract the value of letter a, and perform some checkings for special characters.

You may start with this:

```
   main(){
       int i,j;
       printf("Enter a message to encode:");
       gets(number);
       int codes[125];
       for(int i = 0; i<strlen(number); i++){
           codes[i] = toupper(number[i]) - 'A' + 1;    // note that 'A' represents the code for letter A. 
                                                       // +1 is because you want A to be 1.
       }
   }
```

Note that it is just a guideline, you need to add another features I explained above. The numerical result resides in codes in this case.

Answer (score 0):

First, add a null character at the end of `text`:

```
char  text[]={'         ','A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z','.',',',':','?','\0'};
```

Use `strchr` to find the location of the character in text.

```
for(int i = 0; i < strlen(number); i++){
    int loc = (int)(strchr(text, number[i]) - &text[0]);
    // save the loc in another array or do whatever you want.
}
```

You should also ensure that there is no invalid character in `number`(`'a'` in input wont work as `text` only contains uppercase characters).